# Unable to use methods of one solution in another even after adding references

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have two different VS projects:

1) Utilities 
2) Modules

In the Utilities project, I have a Library.cs
In Library.cs, I have a method `Login()`.
I have defined Library.cs as a  public static class
I have also defined Login as a public static method

In the Modules project, I have a test class Test1.cs
I have added using Utilities in this class.
I have also added reference to the Utilities.dll (Add reference --> browse to bin folder --> Release)
Now, when I try:

```
Library.Login();
```

it says there is no definition for Login() in Library.cs

I have tried cleaning the solution, and rebuilding it as well. Am I doing something wrong or missing something?

Comment: What namespace your `Library` class is inside of?

Comment: Why are you referencing by Browsing to the dll, why don't you reference by Project instead?  That should make it work for you and then you don't have to worry about deployment issues.

Comment: is it possible it is getting confused with some other class named Library in another namespace?  If you hover over Library in the editor window it should show you the fully qualified namespace.

Comment: Please post the code for `Library`, and the code that tries to use it.

Comment: Check your project .NET levels; I suspect this is a case where you have a mismatched library (say a .NET 2 library trying to load a .NET 4 library)

Comment: Is `Login()` static? If not, you need a `Library` object first.

Comment: @zerkms: the namespace for Library.cs is Utilities.

Comment: @Oded: Yes Login() is static.

Comment: @ScottWylie: I tried referencing by project, but when I'm in the Project tab, it doesn't show me any project.

Comment: If you can't see the project in the Projects tab there's something very wrong then. What are the project types and the .NET versions of each?

Comment: @Strillo: Both projects are using .NET Framework 4

Answer (score 0):

Just guess..

Look on you project's `.NET Framework` versions. It seems that they compiled against different versions of framework.

Most often this is a case of that kind of behavior.

Hope this helps.

Comment: usually Visual Studio will give an error when you try to reference a newer dll than the current project's framework supports and then places a warning symbol next to the name of the imported library

Comment: True, but what happens if first you bind it with the same version, let's say `2.0`, after change the DLL's project to `4.0`.? The scenario, imo, is very simliar.

Comment: If I recall, the next time you build, it still gives you the same warning symbol

Comment: @AnthonyShaw: yes, if you pay attention to the `tree view`, so expand the `Reference` node, but if you do not, which probably OP's does, you will get just compile time error. It happened different times to me, and will happen again.